# how to gracefully handle rsync failing, sometimes, to correctly read a directory?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, rsync, automounting, autofs

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fully updated on remote webserver
Running rsync 3.1.1 on remote webserver

I have a fairly simple setup where I allow some users to manage a set of publicly accessible files.

Instead of giving them access to the remote web server, I have setup a share on the local office network (`\localshare\`) where they can copy files to and create, delete, and arrange files and folders as they see fit.

Once a day I then have an rsync which runs from the remote web server and synchronizes the public www folder (`\publicwww`) with the `\localshare\`.

Most of the time this works perfectly.  However, *every now and then* it seems that rsync is not correctly reading the full list of folders and files, which results in it deleting (nearly) everything on the public www folder and leaving everything inaccessible on `\publicwww\` (because it's all gone) until the next sync (which usually corrects the problem).

My best guess is that, since the web server is offsite, there are occasional connection difficulties and rsync simply "times out", unable to read the full list of folders and files in the directory, and then simply gives up, assuming, incorrectly, that there are no more folders or files in the directory.

For example, assume I have the following subfolders in `\localshare\`:

`\localshare\folderA`
`\localshare\folderB`
`\localshare\folderC`

Usually this will synchronize just fine and I will end up with:

`\publicwww\folderA`
`\publicwww\folderB`
`\publicwww\folderC`

But sometimes I will find only:

`\publicwww\folderA`

How can I handle this situation more gracefully?

I tried checking the rsync logs, and I see no indication of a failure to read the full directory.

Just...

```
2019/08/19 09:15:01 [18996] building file list
2019/08/19 09:15:04 [18996] *deleting   folderB/
```

....and then on to deleting all the other folders.

So the problem may be with the way I'm connecting to the `\localshare\` from the Ubuntu server.  I'm using autofs to mount `\localshare\` as a local directory on the Ubuntu server, and then rsync synchronizes the remote `\localshare\` with the local `\publicwww\` directory on the server.  Perhaps because of this layer of abstraction, rsync has no way to tell the difference between a folder that has been fully read, and a mount that has timed out?

1. How can I more definitively troubleshoot this issue to determine that my theory that it is simply a connection timeout is correct?
2. Is there some way I can mitigate this scenario elegantly using rsync?
3. Is there some other way I can work around this problem?  I thought of first syncing `\localshare\` with an intermediate folder on the remote server like `\publicwwwtemp\`, and then only syncing `\publicwwwtemp\` with `\publicwww\` if the log file shows there were no problems with the first sync.  But the rsync log file doesn't seem to show that rsync is even aware that it failed to get a complete directory listing.

Here's my rsync command:

```
rsync -rtvu --perms --chmod=D750,F640 --owner --group --chown=root:www-data --delete-delay --progress --exclude="Info.txt" --exclude="Sync-Logs" --exclude="lost+found" --log-file=/var/log/rsync.publicwww.files.$(date +%Y%m%d).log /Fileserver.mount/localshare/ /publicwww/
```

Comment: it sounds like you have a problem with your network or your file-server.  you should make an effort to identify and fix the cause of the problem before wasting time on the symptoms.

Comment: what leads you to believe that?  the problem is with the "network", i.e. the Internet which connects the `\localshare\ ` and the `\publicwww\ `.  I can't "fix" the Internet.  I need a solution that will gracefully handle an unpredictable Internet.

Comment: if your file-server can't reliably provide access to files and directories, then it is broken and needs to be fixed.   if the reason for your file-server being unreliable is that your network infrastructure is broken, then that needs to be fixed.   papering over the symptoms does not fix anything.

Comment: that's fine in an ideal world with unlimited resources.  in the real world, the Internet is a chain of physical cables and routers and ISPs, and that chain is only as strong as its weakest link.  furthermore, while I could spend more money to upgrade certain sections of that chain (money which is outside of the budget), there remain certain links that are unconditionally and permanently beyond my control.  are you telling me that there is no method for performing a reliable rsync or at least a graceful rsync failure over an unreliable Internet?

Comment: i'm saying that your unreliable file-server is the problem.  rsync issues are just the symptom.  fixing the file-server will get rid of the symptoms, but hiding the symptoms will not fix the actual problem.

Comment: since it seems to not be obvious: a file server should NOT sometimes work and sometimes not work. It should consistently show the actual files and directories to clients, not just some subset of them.

Comment: i have no issues with the file server showing some files and directories except in the context of my rsync synchronization script which runs over the internet.  that's why my question is about how to troubleshoot rsync - not how to fix a file server.

Comment: file-servers do not, as a general rule, have perverse code that implements stuff like "if rsync then screw up".   rsync may be the only thing you've *noticed* having a problem, but it is NOT the cause or the problem, it's a symptom.  The problem is that your file-server is not behaving reliably.

Comment: and what do you think rsync code does when it can no longer access a directory while in the process of building a file list?

Comment: Produce an error message and abort, not go on a rampage deleting stuff just because the file-server timed out.  From the rsync man page:  "If the sending side detects any I/O errors, then the deletion of any files at the destination will be automatically disabled.  This is to prevent temporary filesystem failures (such as NFS errors) on the sending side from causing a massive deletion of files on the destination.  You can override this with the `--ignore-errors` option."

Comment: If your file-server just silently pretends that directories or files don't exist, that's not the fault of rsync.  As I keep saying but you keep not hearing: you have mis-diagnosed the problem. The problem is the file-server, not rsync.   Try, for example, running rsync over ssh, or setting up rsyncd to provide access to the same files.  i.e. avoid using the broken file server.

Comment: `Produce an error message and abort, not go on a rampage deleting stuff just because the file-server timed out. From the rsync man page: "If the sending side detects any I/O errors, then the deletion of any files at the destination will be automatically disabled. This is to prevent temporary filesystem failures (such as NFS errors) on the sending side from causing a massive deletion of files on the destination. You can override this with the --ignore-errors option."`
You could have started with this and saved us both some time.

Comment: i didn't think it needed to be said until you showed yourself to be so resistant to hearing something you didn't want to hear.   for rsync to do anything other than that would be extremely aberrant behaviour - for **any** program.   So, you have two basic options: 1. find what's wrong with your file-server and fix it. or 2. bypass the faulty file-server and use another method to access the files (e.g. rsync over ssh, or configuring `rsyncd`).  option 2 is good in the short term, but option 1 will be necessary eventually.

Comment: well, necessary if you have other reasons to use samba or whatever it is you're using.   If providing access to those files for rsync is the only reason you're running it  (or mounting the share on your web server) then rsync over ssh or rsyncd are good long-term solutions.